# What is the ideal gas enthalpy?

Tags: thermodynamics

In Cengel's Thermodynamics, the enthalpy of air at $25^{\circ} C$ is calculated as follows:

$(1.005\  kJ/kg \ ^{\circ}C)(25 ^{\circ}C)=25.125\  kJ$

But at the appendix table, the enthalpy of water at $25 ^{\circ}$ is $299 =(1.005 kJ/kg·K)(25+273.15))$

So which is correct?

You can also see these two sites:

https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Enthalpy-of-Moist-Air

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-properties-d_1257.html

So which is correct?

Comment: Just a matter of units I guess.

Comment: I don't think so. Because of the lots of usage of the both forms?!

Comment: I think I've found the answer:

Comment: Note! - that the enthalpy is 0 kJ/kg at 0oC. This is not correct according the definition of enthalpy in the thermodynamics, but for practical purposes in air psychrometrics this assumption is good enough since our interest is the enthalpy difference.

Comment: I really don't know the source of the assumption. because we can use real value without confusion

Comment: There is enthalpy with the plimsoll symbol, to indicate standard conditions (usually 25 °C or 298.15 K). It is more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

An answer could be that there is not "absolute enthalpy".

You can only compute variations of enthalpy. In the first cas, you have the variation of enthalpy when température is raised from 0°C to 25°C. You can decide that the enthalpy is zero à 0 ° C and you'll find an "absolute enthalpy".

In the second cas, it seems that the zero level is at 0 K (I am not sure). In all the cases, you only need to compute variations of enthalpy and you'll never have problem, whatever reference level is chosen.

Sorry for my poor english !